# salesforce display data as column based series?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there any tag like `<apex:pageblockTable>` but to show the rows in column order?

Ie . Currently

```
 Name :  Age : country

 Bharath : 25 : INDIA

 Graham  : 26 : UK

 Andrew  : 27 : US
```

Now the expected format is

```
Name :   Bharath : Graham : Andrew

Age  :     25    : 26     : 27

Country:   IND   : UK     : US
```

Comment: I don't think there is any VF page tag is available. There is a similar SFSE link. Please check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-do-i-transpose-rows-and-columns-in-pageblocktable

Comment: You're going to have to do the conversion yourself in `Apex`.

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not aware of any component which will help you transpose your table but you can get this with some simple css and html.

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="TableTransposeController">
    <style>
        #transposeTable tr { 
            display: block;
            float: left; 
        }
        #transposeTable th,#transposeTable td {
            display: block;
            border-bottom-style: inset;
            border-bottom-width: thin;
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px;
            padding-top:5px;
            padding-bottom:5px;
            border-left-style: outset;
        }
        #transposeTable th{
            background: #f2f3f3;
            font-weight: bold;
            min-width:75px;
        }
        #transposeTable td{
            background: white;
        }
        #transposeTable th:first-child,#transposeTable td:first-child{
            border-top-style: outset;
            border-top-width: thin;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <table id="transposeTable">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!allContacts}" var="c">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!c.FirstName}</td>
                    <td>{!c.LastName}</td>
                    <td>{!c.Email}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class TableTransposeController {

    public List getallContacts() {
        return [Select FirstNAme,LastName,Email from Contact limit 5];
    }

}
```

Note: I have not handled horizontal overflow of this table as I believe this kind of representation is better suited when you have many fields to show for fewer records. e.g. When you compare two cell phone features side by side.